# Struggling to understand Lambda expressions with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm very new to this and I can't get my head around the examples I am seeing online. I have been trying to use a lambda statement to sort a list like with the example code I found online:

```
public void Linq29()
{
string[] words = { "cherry", "apple", "blueberry" };

var sortedWords = words.OrderBy(word => word.Length);

Log.WriteLine("The sorted list of words (by length):");
foreach (var w in sortedWords)
{
    Log.WriteLine(w);
}
```

}

I've read a lot of information about how it works, but I can't just get my head around how 'word' can start referring to the items in the list of words.

Can anyone help put this in very simple terms so I can start understanding it.

Thanks.

Comment: in lambda statements the item before => is a variable declaration, you can put anything there and it will translate to a variable of the list type.

Comment: [SO] is not a tutorial service, and you need a tutorial on *delegates*. Lambdas are just a way of creating a method and delegate very easily.

Comment: also it seems that you didn't tried and researched enough, before asking

Comment: I really disagree with "the policy" here. A guy comes and asks a question, users from this site should come and give answers or at least guidance. Those who do not wish to do so, are free not to. But sticking to such purisms is ridiculous. This is a web resource to provide help to those who come ask for it. It may not always be possible or be suiting, but the poster requiring studying or learning about a subject does not prevent him from being eligible to ask here.

Comment: @Richard I think this would fall into the "a specific programming problem" and does not fall into the "off-topic" points in the help center. I think it's a valid specific question that may prove useful to other readers. If anything, it's wrongly tagged since "lambda expressions" are not "linq", but it's a common confusion for beginners and a good answer might prove useful to the topic.

Comment: @Veverke If you want discussion of the "no tool/tutorial/… recommendation policy" please go to [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/). The policy has stood for a long time and for good reasons, but this is not the place for that discussion.

Comment: @Jcl It appears I'm not the only one to think this is not a quick answer: There is nothing in the Q to suggest the OP understands what a "delegate" is (a non-trivial concept itself), so any quick answer about a shortcut to delegates is unlikely to be sufficient.

Comment: @Richard yes, well, as you say, meta is the right place to discuss this, not here. On the very specific topic though, I personally had used delegates plenty when lambdas were added to C#, and I got a bit confused understanding the lambda syntax... yes: nothing that I couldn't solve by a good slow read of the official documentation and some testing, but nonetheless, I could have used a "down-to-earth" explanation back then. Again, that's the democratic part of S.O.... if many don't agree, then close the question. I agree with democracy :-)

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
var sortedWords = words.OrderBy(word => word.Length);
```

uses a so-called lambda expression, which is a concept separate from Linq. The same functionality could be implemented by using a separate function

```
public static int function(string word)
{
    return word.Length;
}
```

and using it as follows.

```
var sortedWords = words.OrderBy(function);
```

the lambda expression `word => word.Length` is much shorter and defines a similar function inline. In this formulattion, `word` (on the left-hand side) defines a name for the argument.

Answer (score 2):

> I've read a lot of information about how it works, but I can't just get my head around how 'word' can start referring to the items in the list of words.

`OrderBy` is an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`, which is what your list of words is.

`OrderBy` can enumerate over the elements itself because it knows `words` is of type `IEnumerable<T>`.

`OrderBy` however requires a "keySelector" to let it know what you want to order by. The `keySelector` is a delegate type. This should take a parameter and return something (MSDN calls it "A function to extract a key from an element").

```
word => word.Length
```

word is the parameter, and word.Length is the method body.

So you are taking the word, and then returning its length.

Answer (score 1):

Think of "word" as being the parameter you would pass to a function that would sort the elements.

What is it that you need to sort the elements of a sequence ? First of all, you need a criteria that establishes, for any given element in the sequence, whether it should preceed or not the subsequent element. Usually you will define it via a function, because a function can take any number of elements/parameters and "state"/return "one single affirmation/thing" regarding the input elements it received. In our case, a sort function, upon receiving two elements, will say whether the 1st should preceed or not the 2nd when ordering the elements.

After you have such criteria defined, you would need to go over each element and, based on a sorting criteria (described above) check if the current element should preceed or not the next one in orderning the sequence.

That's why the framework gives you a Sort method that receives a function. It will do the work of looping over every sequence element for you and check the result of the sorting criteria, and based on that, order the elements.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a stab at this using the concept that helped me get my head round lambdas in the first place.  Lets look at the lambda:

```
word => word.Length
```

This is short hand for `(word) => word.Length` which in turn is shorthand for `(word) => {return word.Length;}`

this lambda is in turn short hand for an anonymous function *with type inference*, the below is therefore only pseudo code:

```
delegate(var word) {return word.Length;}
```

The compiler CAN infer the type of var, thus in *Your example* this is short hand for:

```
delegate(string word) {return word.Length;}
```

which is in turn shorthand for (again the output type is infered so this is specific to your example):

```
    static class [compilerInventMeAClassNamePlease] 
    {
       static int [compilerInventMeAMethodNamePlease] (string word) 
       {
          return word.Length;
       }
    }
...
    [a call to][compilerInventMeAMethodNamePlease]
```

These classes and method really are made by the compiler.

Thus a lambda is a way to *inline* create a anonymous class / method which you have not given a name and define it.  Everything on the left of the `=>` is signature.  While you are getting comfortable with it you might find it easier to write them, at least initially, in the long-hand format:

```
(string word, int multiply) => { return word.Length * multiply;  }
```

Please note the class generated by the lambda may not be static but a real instance class with its own instance fields,  this is due to a concept called a closure which is the next thing to investigate when you are comfortable with lambdas

Answer (score 1):

> how 'word' can start referring to the items in the list of words

Check the method signature which is:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector
)
```

So it's an extension method for the `IEnumerable<TSource>`. It expects a parameter of type `Func<TSource, TKey>` which in itself is a delegate, this is why you provide an anonymous function as the parameter: `(word) => { word.Length; }`. The program knows that `word` is the same type as an item of your collection `words` because `word` is a parameter of type `TSource`, which is of the same type as the `this IEnumerable<TSource> source` that the method `OrderBy()` extends from.